# What is the total momentum of EM fields?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, momentum, classical-electrodynamics, magnetic-moment

I have an assignment where i have to find the total momentum of an EM field. Imagine a perfect magnetic dipole in (0,0,0) with dipole moment $$ \mathbf{m} = m\mathbf{\hat{z}} $$

And also a point charge in (0,0,0). I found the momentum density of the configuration: $$ \mathbf{g} = \frac{\mu_0mq}{(4\pi)^2r^5}\mathbf{\hat{z}}\times\mathbf{\hat{r}} $$
My question then is, what is the total momentum of the EM field? I don't understand the question, since i have a density, so wouldn't i need some volume to integrate over?
I know that the total momentum is defined $$ \mathbf{p} = \epsilon_0 \int_V \mathbf{g}d\tau $$
So i would need some volume. or?

Comment: I’ve seen similar problems where the goal is to integrate over all of space. But in this case the momentum density you’re calculating is going to integrate to zero by symmetry, so I’m not sure what to tell you.

Comment: I've added the homework-and-exercises tag. In the future, please use this tag on this type of question.

Comment: It is against policy to provide answers to homework questions. @MichaelSeifert

Comment: I have never seen $d\tau$ used to mean an element of volume.

Comment: @G.Smith Griffiths uses that notation in his E&M book

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Oh i see. So the symmetry around the z axis tells us that the total momentum of x and y directions is 0, and since the momentum density in the z direction is 0, then the total momentum is just 0.